# Переименовывание файлов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток! 
Мне дали такое вот задание: "Задан путь к директории с музыкальными файлами (в названии которых нет номеров, а только названия песен) и текстовый файл, хранящий полный список песен с номерами и названиями в виде строк формата «01. Freefall [6:12]». Напишите скрипт, который корректирует имена файлов в директории на основе текста списка песен."
Я его, в принципе, сделал, но есть нюансы. Во-первых, наверняка переименовывание можно было сделать без вот этих двух циклов, а как-нибудь проще. Во-вторых, если есть файлы со схожими названиями, например, Dog.mp3 и Dogs.mp3, скрипт найдет и переименует файл Dog.mp3 два раза. Ну и сам вопрос: какой есть оптимальный способ решения этих проблем?

```
def fix_names(folder, textfile):
    names = open(textfile, 'r').read().splitlines() #Собираю имена файлов из файла
    tracks = [file for file in os.listdir(folder)] #Собираем список файлов в папке
    for track in tracks:
        for name in names:
            if track.split('.')[0] in name:
                os.rename(folder+os.path.sep+track, folder+os.path.sep+name.split(' ')[0]+' '+track)
```

Список файлов выглядит, например, так:

```
За облаками.mp3  
Лай.mp3  
Мечтай.mp3
```

Содержимое файла вот так:

```
01. Лай [2:51]  
02. Мечтай [3:15]  
03. За облаками [3:20]
```

Comment: вы можете привести пример списка файлов и пример содержимого текстового файла?

Comment: @MaxU исправил вопрос

Comment: А время звучания (то что в квадратных скобках) должно быть в итоговом имени или нет?

Comment: @MaxU нет, не должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используется Python v3.4+, то можно воспользоваться модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\Temp\.data\769010')
mask = '*.mp3'
conf_file = Path(r'C:\Temp\.data\769010\config.txt')

cfg = {}
with conf_file.open(encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line.split('[')[0]
        cfg[s.split('.')[1].strip()] = s.strip()
#print(cfg)

for f in path.glob(mask):
    name = f.name.replace(f.suffix, '')
    f.rename(str(f).replace(name, cfg.get(name)))
```

Итого мы:

1. один раз читаем текстовый файл
2. создаем из него словарь вида:

---

```
{'Лай': '01. Лай', 'Мечтай': '02. Мечтай', 'За облаками': '03. За облаками'}
```

---

3. один раз читаем MP3 файлы в указанной директории и переименовываем их на ходу, используя для этого словарь из п. 2

Результат:

---

```
In [94]: list(path.glob(mask))
Out[94]:
[WindowsPath('C:/Temp/.data/769010/01. Лай.mp3'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/.data/769010/02. Мечтай.mp3'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/.data/769010/03. За облаками.mp3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переименовать `За облаками.mp3` в `03. За облаками.mp3`, если во входном файле есть строчка `03. За облаками [3:20]`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: number-songs <songs>"""
import re
import sys
from contextlib import suppress
from pathlib import Path

songs = Path(sys.argv[1]).read_text()
for number, song in re.findall(r'(?m)^(\d+)\.\s*(.*?)\s*\[[^]]+\]$', songs):
    path = Path(song + '.mp3')
    with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
        path.replace(f"{number}. {path}")
```